# Celery error in scheduled task execution

Tags: python, celery

I have an instance of Celery running with Redis server in an archlinux machine.
In this instance I have defined some tasks to be executed every X minutes. The schedule is working correctly (if I check the logs, the tasks are being called), but there is a task outputting an error.
The task is to run another python script. **If I run this script manually, it works perfectly**. But when celery try to execute it, I receive this error:

```
WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-93] Exception in thread Thread-6:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

The tasks.py is:

```
@periodic_task(
    run_every=(crontab(minute='*/15')),
    name="sm37_auto",
    ignore_result=True
)
def sm37_auto():
    comando_sm37 = os.system("python /home/user/sm37.py")
    background_thread=threading.Thread(target=comando_sm37)
    background_thread.start()
    return 'ejecuta SM37 ok'
```

Could somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, you are talking about `/home/user/sm37.py` which works perfectly. The script `task.py` will execute fine as well because it has nothing to execute: syntactically the function is correct.

The problem is that when you start a thread, you need to pass something executable as `target` and you pass a return value instead. Consider making a change:

```
def sm37_thread():
    comando_sm37 = os.system("python /home/user/sm37.py")

def sm37_auto():
    background_thread=threading.Thread(target=sm37_thread)
    background_thread.start()
    return 'ejecuta SM37 ok'
```

Comment: I have tried, but still getting the error.
It used to work ok a few weeks ago. It start to output this error without any change.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
comando_sm37 = os.system("python /home/user/sm37.py")
```

this executes the /home/user/sm37.py scripts and returns the process exit status, which is an integer error code (where `0` means 'no error' and everything else is an error).

Then you have:

```
background_thread=threading.Thread(
    target=comando_sm37
)
```

where you try to create a thread (why you want to do so in this context is way beyond my imagination but that's another topic), passing an integer as the target callable.

To make a long story short, this code makes no sense at all.

Using `os.system` to execute a Python script is already quite questionable (python code can import other python code, you don't need `os.system` for this) but well,  you might have reasons to do so (legacy code, whatever...). But starting a thread from a celery task, really ???